# Rails run :get route within /new and /edit _form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, render

I have a `_form` for `new` and `edit` for a `@Giveaway` object. Within this form I have a field for a random winner.

I want to populate this field by calling the method `giveaways#random_winner` with `<%= button_to "Randomly Pick Winner!", {:action => 'choose_winner'}, :method => :get %>`, but I am getting this error `No route matches {:action=>"choose_winner", :controller=>"giveaways"}` when loading `/giveaways/new`.

Here is my controller:

```
  def choose_winner
    random_winner = SubscriberUser.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:subscriber_id).sample(1)
    session[:random_winner] = random_winner
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Here are the routes that I have tried. I'm not very good at non-scaffold routes yet:

```
  resources :giveaways do
    member do        
      get 'choose_winner' => 'giveaways#choose_winner'
      #tried get :choose_winner, as: :choose_winner
      #tried get 'new/choose_winner'
      #tried get 'choose_winner'
      #tried get 'choose_winner', to: 'giveaways#choose_winner', as: 'choose_winner'
    end
  end
```

**Question** -- Why is the page not loading when I have defined the controller and action in the route? Will I have to reload the page when I do run that route... is there a better way to get at this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes.rb is close

```
resources :giveaways do 
  member do
    get :choose_winner
  end
end
```

And then I would use a Rails route helper so you don't have to worry about setting the action/controller yourself.

`<%= button_to "Randomly Pick Winner", choose_winner_giveaway_path(@giveaway), method: :get %>`

Comment: Thank you. What I am worried about is that the new method does not have an object id yet.

Comment: You could make it a collection route and pass an ID as a param. Then handle those two cases separately